rendenderMessageText in gifted chat not accepting updated state
I am using react-native-gifted-chat@2.6.4 in my expo project..
Here is my Gifted chat component:
<GiftedChat
          messages={messages}
          onSend={(messages) => onSend(messages)}
          user={{ _id: user.id }}
          renderInputToolbar={renderInputToolbar}
          renderSend={renderSend}
          renderMessageAudio={renderMessageAudio}
          renderMessage={(props) => renderMessage(props)}
          renderMessageText={(props) => renderMessageText(props)}
          textInputProps={styles.textinput}
          renderMessageImage={renderMessageImage}
          listViewProps={{
            contentContainerStyle: { paddingBottom: 0, marginBottom: 0 },
          }}
          bottomOffset={0}
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          containerStyle={{ borderTopWidth: 0 }}
        />

Here is my renderMessage function:
const renderMessage = (props) => {
  console.log({forwardHeader});
}

and here is renderMessageText:
const renderMessageText = (props) => {
  console.log({forwardHeader});
}

when this state forwardHeader is updated then i am getting updated state in renderMessage but not getting updatedState in renderMessageText
Is there any issue in renderMessageText for what it is not getting updated state,,
State is created globally, no worry for that because i am getting updated one in one render of GiftedChat but not getting updated in other function renderMessageText
I have tried almost all ways including even usecallBack for rendering it again as state change, but still it is not worked
